# Can I run all the reports in a given folder from Report Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

Having an issue with running reports here. I have a folder on the Report Server that contains several reports, reports are added and deleted on a weekly basis in this folder.

I know how to run a given report, but ideally what I'm looking for is running all the reports in the folder, is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Mike

Comment: `running all the reports` what does this mean exactly? you run a report and it is on one page.

Comment: Dear BhupeshC, in short I have a folder with around 15 reports in it, these are Report Server reports. To run each report individually will take a while, so I want them to run together. So, what I want to be able to do is somehow run all the reports in this folder, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This has different answers depending on whether you need to enter parameter values for any of these reports in order to run them.

If you don't, or if the parameter values are predictable (for example, every report takes a date range, but it's the same range for all of them, like the last 90 days), you could use the two SSRS web services.

For example, you could use the report management service (I believe it's called ReportingServices2005) to get the names of the reports in that folder, and the report execution service (ReportExecution2005) to provide parameters and execute each report.  The report execution service can return you the report output in your choice of format (PDF, HTML, Excel, etc.)

Once you had the output of the report, you could direct it to a printer, save it to a file share, or email it as an attachment to whoever it needed to go to.

Here's a link to someone doing 90% of what you want to do:  http://nickturner.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/creating-ssrs-report-as-a-pdf-programatically/

If every report needs a human to enter parameters, it comes down to making that easier for the human to do.  The same idea of retrieving the names of the reports could apply, but then you'd display each report in turn in a `ReportViewer` control, and once the report was run, change what report the `ReportViewer` points to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ann. No report needs parameters as I have saved them as part of the report - they are all located on the Report Server in a specific folder. Because there are many of these reports I want to be able to run them automatically and send them in the same email to given recipients.

Comment: Then I think you'll need to do a bit of programming, as I outline above. The web service looks intimidating, but it's actually simple to use.  Here's a link to someone doing 90% of what you want to do:  http://nickturner.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/creating-ssrs-report-as-a-pdf-programatically/