# Is it possible to run all the reports in a given folder from report server?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a folder with around 15 reports in it, these are Report Server reports. To run each report individually will take a while, so I want them to run together. So, what I want to be able to do is somehow run all the reports in this folder, is this possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by running all reports? Export to file? Caching them?

Comment: Hi Jonathon, Thanks for your reply. The requirement is to sent the excel  as an attachment to an email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I run all the reports in a given folder from Report Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479871/can-i-run-all-the-reports-in-a-given-folder-from-report-server)

Comment: Hi Shawn, Thanks for your reply. Yes, this is the part of my requirement. In addition i need to export all the reports to an excel.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of an ambiguous question. Let me explain. What are you asking specifically?

Q: Can you run multiple reports at the same time?
A: Yes, and there are several ways to accomplish this.
  1. You can use SQL agents
  2. Use batch files with task scheduler
  3. Use an SSIS package and use an agent to run them at specific times...etc...

Hopefully one of the reports does not depend on another and another thing that you have to take in to consideration is how hard you will be hitting the SSRS or SQL server. Running them all at one time may take longer than one at a time. depending on the bandwidth of the SQL Server and what tables are going to be locked up during each of these processes.

You might want to give a little more detail in your question...

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for your reply.

Comment: For Example: I created the reports for  in SSRS 

Sales Report A,
Sales Report B and 
Sales Report C 

and deployed the reports to the folder 'SALES OPERATIONS' on the report server.

Instead of running each report i want  to run all the  3 reports in the 'SALES OPERATIONS' folder at once and export all the 3  reports in same excel workbook.

Comment: @user6237116 in that case, develop an SSIS package An SSIS package also gives you the option of emailing the workbook too which you mentioned in a previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an SSIS package, especially as it also one of the options presented by @Michael that can email the Excel workbook too which you mentioned in an earlier comment.

The following resource covers quite well the execution and export of an SSRS report using SSIS, including code you will need as a starting point: [Executing an SSRS Report from an SSIS Package](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3475/execute-a-sql-server-reporting-services-report-from-integration-services-package/).

You could save some time in coding the solution by using the following custom Task that can be integrated into SSIS: [SSIS ReportGenerator Task](https://reportgeneratortask.codeplex.com/).

There is one problem in your requirements though which is *merging reports into one Excel workbook* where I assume you want separate sheets for each report within the same workbook?

Reporting Services can use multiple worksheets (to divide a report up into pages a.k.a pagination) but only for a single report; it can't merge reports into one Excel file. This can be accomplished with custom code however. There's  a somewhat basic example here: [Merging workbooks into a master workbook with separate sheet for each file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847151/merging-workbooks-into-a-master-workbook-with-seperate-sheet-for-each-file).

Answer (score 0):

One way to run all the reports at once is to add subscription to all of them and set same subscription start time in all of the reports. what will happen is once the start time arrived all the reports will run simultaneously and will generate excel/pdf (any format specified) file at shared location.